# ¿Cómo importar un gran lote de iconos a Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen

Gracias por leer mi pregunta. Tengo el siguiente problema. Cuento con muchos archivos de imagen en formato PNG que debo agregar a mi proyecto para ser usados como iconos de notificación. El problema es que debo agregarlos de uno en uno pues si uso la herramienta que dispone Android Studio de importar múltiples drawables no le aplica el formato de notificación a las imágenes, lo que produce que en algunos dispositivos no se vean los iconos.¿Existe alguna manera de importar como notificación muchas imágenes a la vez al proyecto? Gracias a todos

Cómo referencia estoy usando la versión 4.0 de Android Studio

Comment: Hola, si son jpg podrias entrar desde el explorador de archivos de windows, mac o linux hasta donde se encuentran los drawables que es en src/drawable  y pegar ahi todos los iconos. Si necesitas convectir tus svg a vectores xml la unica forma es la que comentas creo :D

Comment: Gracias Carlosgub. Hubiera sido ideal que existiera alguna forma de hacerlo desde el mismo Android Studio.

Comment: Si claro, ahora muchas veces los diseñadores usan zepplin u otras herramientas que se integran a android studio y tiene la herramienta para importar el icono de manera sencilla al proyecto :D

Comment: Considera agregar lo que trataste , revisa [ask], saludos!